# Github Pull Request Builder fails due to java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: github

I'm scratching my head over this one. One of my PR builders triggered when there's new pull requests but it kept failing with ERROR: Publisher com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubCommitNotifier. I have "write and push" to this repository like my 2 other pull request builders which work fine on 2 other repositories. Has anyone run into same problem? Thanks,

plugin versions:

git v2.3.4, GitHub API v1.59, GitHub v1.10, Github Pull Request Builder v1.16-8

error log:

> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> Setting commit status on GitHub for https://github.com/Company/repos-one/commit/fab14d3b033743c186b66abcda8ba0a00f70f73c

01:06:44 Setting commit status on GitHub for https://github.com/Company/repos-one/commit/fab14d3b033743c186b66abcda8ba0a00f70f73c

01:06:44 ERROR: Publisher com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubCommitNotifier aborted due to exception

01:06:44 java.io.FileNotFoundException: api.github.com/repos/Company/repos-one/statuses/fab14d3b033743c186b66abcda8ba0a00f70f73c

01:06:44    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)

01:06:44    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)

01:06:44    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.parse(Requester.java:383)

01:06:44    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester._to(Requester.java:185)

01:06:44    at org.kohsuke.github.Requester.to(Requester.java:160)

01:06:44    at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.createCommitStatus(GHRepository.java:702)

01:06:44    at org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository.createCommitStatus(GHRepository.java:714)

01:06:44    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubCommitNotifier.updateCommitStatus(GitHubCommitNotifier.java:127)

01:06:44    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.GitHubCommitNotifier.perform(GitHubCommitNotifier.java:84)

01:06:44    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:780)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:744)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:693)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1770)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)

01:06:44    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)

01:06:44 Disconnecting from VPN service.

01:06:44 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

01:06:44 Setting status of 56b8b7a5d0595d321c46cd3450c6a68873a97480 to FAILURE with url  company.ci.cloudbees.com/job/HL-Pull-Request-Builder/7/ and message: Merged build finished.

01:06:44 Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1):

problem caused by having authorized tokens of users who don't have push to the repository. Remove those tokens solved it